# capture logs while publish fails

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

Error message showing in Tridion UI is different and  message showing in log file is different. So we want to capture log file data while publishing.
is there API to capture logs while publish fails? like event extension ? 
Apart from below files
cd_deployer.log
cd_core.log

Comment: Refer this question http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/tridion-publishing-error-logs

Comment: Are you able to share the actual error and how it is different between the UI and the log file? That will help focus the answers you get back and give better context to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Where in the publish steps appears this error?

If the error appears in Deploying or Commiting Deployment, you should search in Deployer Service's logs (cd_deployer.log and cd_core.log)

If the error appears in trasporting step you sould search in event viewer or %TRIDION_HOME%\log\cd_transport.log

You can change the log level modifying logback.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Core Service to programatically access the items in the Tridion Publish Queue and get additional information about the item and the message the Publishing UI shows.  Check the code below taken my [Publish Queue Monitor Project](https://github.com/rcurlette/TridionPubQMonitor/blob/master/TridionPubQMonitoringService/TridionPubQService.cs).  It should provide you an idea an starting point for accessing that type of information.

However, it will not get the Deployer log information for you, since those failure details are only found within the Deployer logs.

I'd suggest to possibly use something like [LogEntries](https://logentries.com) and send the failures to it.

For my scenario, I used their Log4Net extension. [It's painfully simple to setup and use with .Net](https://logentries.com/doc/dotnet/).  You can also do something similar with the Java side, possibly using a File extension from LogEntries (to monitor the Deployer Logs (we do that too) and then you can set an alert based on some text within the log file.  Finally, logentries lets you send emails to people when an 'alert' goes off based on a regular expression.

Core Service Code to Scan the Publish Queue...from [Publish Queue Monitor Project](https://github.com/rcurlette/TridionPubQMonitor/blob/master/TridionPubQMonitoringService/TridionPubQService.cs)

```
  private List<PublishQueueItem> GetPublishQueueItemsInLastPeriod(CoreServiceClient client)
        {
            var filter = CreateFilter();

            XElement publishTransactions = client.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);
            List<PublishQueueItem> pubQueueItems = new List<PublishQueueItem>();
            foreach(XElement queueItem in publishTransactions.Descendants())
            {
                pubQueueItems.Add(new PublishQueueItem()
                {
                    ID = queueItem.Attribute("ID").Value,
                    Title = queueItem.Attribute("Title").Value,
                    ItemUri = queueItem.Attribute("ItemID").Value,
                    User = queueItem.Attribute("User").Value,
                    Publication = queueItem.Attribute("Publication").Value,
                    PublicationTarget = queueItem.Attribute("PublicationTarget").Value,
                    ItemPath = queueItem.Attribute("ItemPath").Value
                });
            }
            return pubQueueItems;
        }

        private static PublishTransactionsFilterData CreateFilter()
        {
            int timePeriod = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PubQItemsInLastXSeconds"]);
            var filter = new PublishTransactionsFilterData();
            filter.StartDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-(timePeriod));
            filter.EndDate = System.DateTime.Now;

            // Success and Failed are mostly used for testing when we don't have items stuck in rendering
            string publishState = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PublishState"];

            if (publishState == "Rendering")
            {
                filter.PublishTransactionState = PublishTransactionState.Rendering;
                //logger.WriteEntry("Rendering Phase");
            }
            else if (publishState == "Failed")
            {
                filter.PublishTransactionState = PublishTransactionState.Failed;
                //logger.WriteEntry("Failed Phase");
            }
            else if (publishState == "Success")
            {
                filter.PublishTransactionState = PublishTransactionState.Success;
                //logger.WriteEntry("Success Phase");
            }
            return filter;
        }
```