# Monitoring Publish queue for availability metrics

Tags: publishing

I have a requirement to calculate the availability of Publishing function . we have 6 different Targets and need to be able to calculate the availability for each of the target. I can monitor the publish queue for successful vs failures but it does not give me a true failure scenarios because publishing failures can be attributed to user errors , code issues . specifically interested in identifying Publishing failure because of  infrastructural issues.

Answer (score 1):

We've addressed similar stuff in 2 parts:
1: Demonstrating Reliability: Added publish event system code to capture publish details and errors and its phase with details like whether it is rendering or deployment failures and created reporting on the same to demonstrate reliability of the system. We calculate publishing throughput w.r.t success vs failure percentage. Note that we capture these details in a separate db since publishing queue does not preserve transactions when same item is published again and keeps the latest one for each item
2: Monitoring: To report availability of publishing, we use SCOM monitoring for CM/Publisher services and NLB health check for deployers and oData and health check on SQL servers and that covers all systems used during publish and ensures the system is available to execute publish and we can proactively fix any issues with the same.

Also, Tridion logs are a good place to find issues related to any issues within Tridion publishing pipeline. Refer [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/tridion-publishing-error-logs/12536#12536) question for log locations

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response . The challenge is only with publishing becos the publishing functionality is shared between CMS and deployers we have good monitoring for all the critical functionalities and infrastructure components